# CatalogSearch getResultCollection breaks for flat tables

Tags: magento

```
$this->helper('catalogsearch')->getQuery()->getResultCollection();
```

breaks with:

> Call to undefined method
>   Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Flat::getEntityTablePrefix()

when flat tables are on (and there's a `$query` param). Seems like it's expecting EAV tables. Has anyone patched this somehow?

Answer (score -1):

Please refresh your cache and reindex 'Catalog Search Index'